# Find decimal count from shopspring decimal library

Tags: go

I am using [github.com/shopspring/decimal](https://github.com/shopspring/decimal) for decimal related operations in golang instead of float for actual precision.
I have a requirement to find the decimal count for a decimal library value.

eg:-

```
price := decimal.NewFromFloat(0.00355)
fmt.Println("Price:", price)    // Price:0.00355
```

This is how I use the decimal. So now I want to count the number of decimals from the same decimal.
In the above example the decimal count would be `5` since there are five decimal points.

Checked the docs but couldn't find the right operation for this. Can somebody help with this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert decimal value to string, then count number of char after point `.`.

```
0.00355 => "0.00355" => count=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just use [`decimal.Exponent()`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/shopspring/decimal#Decimal.Exponent) and ask the number what its scale is?

https://goplay.tools/snippet/9Y6BP1dcOuA

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shopspring/decimal"
)

func main() {
    x := decimal.NewFromFloat(123.456789)
    s := x.Exponent()

    fmt.Printf("decimal value %v has a scale of %v\n", x, s)

}
```

Which yields

> ```
> decimal value 123.456789 has a scale of -6
> ```

Comment: Thank you. Some how I missed the exponent function. As an improvement we can multiply the same with -1 to get positive number since exponent will be giving a negative number.